existence of third critical point some intuitive explanation
Let $F: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^1$ which is bounded from below and which is proper in the following sense:
$$F(x) \rightarrow \infty \textrm{ for } |x| \rightarrow \infty $$
If F has two relative minima $x_1, x_2$ and they are strict in the following sense: For $x_1, x_2$, we have
$$ \exists \delta_{0} \textrm{ with } 0< |y-x| \leq \delta_{0}: F(y) > F(x)$$
Then F has a third critical point. why is this true, rather than proof, I want some good intuitive explanation or some example.

Think of the graph of $F$ as a mountain range. Imagine you're in the valley surrounding $x_1$ and you want to travel to $x_2$ while climbing the least amount possible.
Given a route $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^d$, i.e.

$\gamma$ is continuous
$\gamma(0)=x_1$, $\gamma(1)=x_2$

(really the route in the actual mountain range would be $(\gamma(t), F(\gamma(t)))$, we compute $$h_\gamma= \sup_t F(\gamma(t)).$$
This is the top height you have to climb to, somewhere along this route. If we want to minimize this, we simply take
$$
c=\inf_\gamma h_\gamma,
$$
where the infimum is taken over all possible routes satisfying the two conditions above. The intuition is that the route realizing this infimum will have you going through a mountain pass, at which there'll be a critical point (or in math terms, $c$ is a critical value).
Being a bit more precise: Suppose $\gamma$ realizes this infimum and $z=\gamma(t_0)$ realizes the supremum. Now if $c$ is not a critical value, then there's some direction $u$ along which $\partial_uF(z)<0$ (i.e. the height decreases along $u$) and so by continuity of this derivative, we should be able to modify $\gamma$ slightly to achieve a lower height $h_\gamma$, contradicting the definition of $c$.
Note that your strict minimum condition precludes this critical value from being either $F(x_1)$ or $F(x_2)$, so this indeed gives a third point.
If you want a proof of this you can look for the aptly named mountain pass theorem.
